How to add date axis correctly in pyqtgraph
code:
        self.graph = pg.PlotWidget(self)
        self.graph.setBackground("w")
        self.graph.showGrid(x=True, y=True)
        pen = pg.mkPen(color=(90, 169, 240),  width=5)
        self.graph.setYRange(0, 1000)
        self.plot = self.graph.plot(
            [],
            [],
            pen=pen,
            symbol='o',
            symbolSize=4,
            symbolBrush="b",
        )
        
        self.widgets.append(self.graph)
        
        
    def optimize_view(self):
        self.graph.setGeometry(6, 0, self.width(), self.height() - 50)
        
    def setup_graph(self, sym):
        if sym != 'USDT':
            try:
                data = self.get_price_history(self.parent().valute, self.time_frame)
            except:
                self.plot.setData([], [])
        else:
            pass
        new_date = datetime.now() - timedelta(len(data) - 1)
        
        res = pd.date_range(min(new_date, datetime.now()),max(new_date, datetime.now())).tolist()
        res = [datetime.timestamp(i) for i in res]
        axis_res = pd.date_range(min(new_date, datetime.now()),max(new_date, datetime.now())).strftime('%d.%m.%Y').tolist()
        self.graph.setYRange(min(data), max(data))
        self.graph.setXRange(min(res), max(res))
        print(len(res), len(data))
        
        date_axis = pg.graphicsItems.DateAxisItem.DateAxisItem(orientation = 'bottom')
        self.graph.setAxisItems(axisItems = {'bottom': date_axis})
        
        self.plot.setData(res, data)
        
    def get_price_history(self, symbol, timeframe):
        exchange = ccxt.binance()
        
        data = exchange.fetch_ohlcv(f'{symbol}/USDT', timeframe)
        
        prices = [candle[3] for candle in data]
        
        return prices

I have my bottom axis with datedelta values. I need to replace it with string dates in format '%d.%m.%Y'. What should I do? I don't understand how text axises works. self.graph bottom axis must contain only str-dates.
get_price_history returns list of float values.

For future reference, please ensure that you provide a more comprehensive and adequate [mre] (which does not mean the full code), not just arbitrary "cuts" from your code base that would force us to trying to guess a possible context of the code, instead of focusing on the actual issue. Please take your time to see [ask] and review the checklist.

While the code has some flaws, the task is clear: use pyqtgraph to interactively plot cryptocurrency data fetched online with ccxt.
As for the main question, pass numeric timestamps, for example
1717977600 translates to Monday, 10 June 2024 00:00:00 and annotate the axis as dates with DateAxisItem.
Plotting is interactive and, consequently, formatting depends on zoom to optimize visual experience. That means, zoom more to see days, zoom less to see months. I would recommend staying with that for starter, and try to customize as the second step, see the docs.
Bellow, I attach a fixed code snippet with a fully-working app, and a screenshort

# file name: bitcoin_plot.py 
# run: python bitcoin_plot.py
import sys
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import ccxt
import pandas as pd
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class BTCUSDTPlotter(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.graph = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.graph.showGrid(x=True, y=True)
        layout.addWidget(self.graph)

    def fetch_and_plot(self):
        # fetch BTC/USDT data from Binance
        exchange = ccxt.binance({'enableRateLimit': True})
        symbol = 'BTC/USDT'
        timeframe = '1d'
        ohlcv_data = exchange.fetch_ohlcv(symbol, timeframe)
        
        # process 
        timestamps = [x[0] / 1000 for x in ohlcv_data]  # convert to seconds
        dates = [datetime.fromtimestamp(ts) for ts in timestamps] # use numeric timestamps
        close_prices = [x[4] for x in ohlcv_data]  # https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/blob/b6ea6bd9b88525c6110ba8f658c727b0ed6bcf62/examples/py/binance-fetch-ohlcv.py#L38

        # plot
        self.graph.plot(timestamps, close_prices, pen=pg.mkPen(color=(0, 120, 200), width=2))
        date_axis = pg.graphicsItems.DateAxisItem.DateAxisItem(orientation='bottom')
        self.graph.setAxisItems({'bottom': date_axis})


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    plotter = BTCUSDTPlotter()
    plotter.fetch_and_plot()
    window.setCentralWidget(plotter)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Wby did u use 4 in close_prices = [x[4] for x in ohlcv_data]?

I follow the documentation: https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/blob/b6ea6bd9b88525c6110ba8f658c727b0ed6bcf62/examples/py/binance-fetch-ohlcv.py#L38
But this is not important - adjust as you wish - what is important does the solution work for you?

I found the way and now all is working. Thank you so much.

Perfect, in that case consider accepting the answer. Following your comment, I  linked the documentation regarding the extraction of closing quotes.
